# Adding an attribute to an HTML tag using IIS Url Rewrite module outbound rule

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, url-rewrite-module

I am required to add a `rel="nofollow"` attribute to all `<a>` tags whose `href` attribute value matches a defined pattern.

I'd thought that it might be possible to do this using the IIS Url Rewrite module, using an outbound rule with a custom tag rewrite to assign the value to the `rel` attribute. The rule would look something like this:

```
<rule name="Shop url rewrite" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml">
    <match filterByTags="CustomTags" customTags="Anchor rel attribute" pattern="^$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="nofollow" />
</rule>
<preConditions>
    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
    </preCondition>
</preConditions>
<customTags>
    <tags name="Anchor rel attribute">
        <tag name="a" attribute="rel" />
    </tags>
</customTags>
```

However, as the existing tags don't have a `rel` attribute, there is nothing for the rule to match against so nothing happens.

Does anyone know if it is possible to add an attribute that doesn't exists to a tag using this technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tricky way to archive this goal using rule like below,

```
<outboundRules>
        <rule name="outbound" stopProcessing="true">
            <match filterByTags="A" pattern="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}&quot; ref=&quot;nofollow" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
```

Comment: The above works if you paste it directly into the configuration file however if you want to use the IDE or use PowerShell to add the value this will not work because the ampersand in &quot; is itself escaped rendering the value meaningless. I found that in Powershell it is OK to use double quotes as long as the value is itself in single quotes. e.g. Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/outboundRules/rule[@name='My rule']/action" -name "value" -value '{R:0}" style="border: solid 10px red;'