# Force <a href="/"></a> to resolve to root of virtual directory rather than site

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7

I have set up a virtual directory on our hosting space for one of our clients. My aim is to make it so that we have a virtual directory for each client that is password protected and that our core site simply provides a list of the available sites to preview. My structure therefore is as follows:

```
www.domain.com (root)
www.domain.com/websiteone/ (virtual directory)
www.domain.com/websitetwo/ (virtual directory)
```

My problem is that an links in "websiteone" that use "/" are resolving to www.domain.com/ rather than to www.domain.com/websiteone/

How do I get around this? Ideally if you could provide an example that uses the plesk control panel that would be ideal as this is all our hosting provider provides us with.

Comment: <a> tag is rendered by browsers. If you look source from your browser you will still see the link as  href="/", in this case your html tags needs to be changed.

Comment: I understand that vgSefa as I am a web developer but there is a server side way of doing this by default in a virtual directory. At least there is on Apache anyway so there should be an IIS equivalent.

Comment: You are right. I made a quick research and found something like that. You can define outboundRule to edit html tags from the config file. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428299/adding-an-attribute-to-an-html-tag-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-outbound-rule

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/" runat="server">Click Me</asp:HyperLink>
```

instead of `<a>`, so "~" will do what you need.